# AudioRecord file size is a little large

Tags: android, audio, recording

I am struggling with this, I have changed the bitrate to reduce the recording filesize, my app correctly posts audio files to a server, yet I want to minimize filesize, this is my record code

```
 private void startRecording() throws IOException {

        String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            throw new IOException("No SD mounted.  It is" + state
                    + ".");

        }

        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(44100);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);


        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath());

        if (!path.exists() && !path.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("The file directory is invalid.");
        }else{

            try {
                archivo = File.createTempFile("audio", ".3gp", path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

        }

        mRecorder.setOutputFile(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);


        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();


    }
```

> I am getting like 336 kb for 1 minute recording right now, I want to
>   decrease it to around 100 - 200 kb per minute without loosing too
>   much quality

Comment: I challenge you to find an audio file of any codec (aac, mp3, flac, ...) from which you can render audio at a bit rate you are asking for ( 100 - 200 kb per minute) ... to attain a reasonable audio quality you need about that PER SECOND not per minute ... this has nothing to do with mobile streaming its pure information theory ... more bits per second means the audio curve is less jagged and easier on the ears ... either accept an increased bit rate or a reduction in quality ...  I suggest you try a bit depth of 8 per sample instead of typical default of 16 bits per sample, mono channel

Comment: hi @ScottStensland i changed the values and the compressor and im getting live 335 kbs / minute , is rasonable and still a good quality

Comment: the thing is that for an app that mostly uses audios as source i dont want to waste like terabytes or gb per month on audios, i think there is another way @ScottStensland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things you can try.

1) use AMR (adaptive multi-rate) for higher compression:

```
recorder.setAudioEncoder(mRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

AMR Wideband and AMR Narrowband are the encoding methods used by the device for telephone calls. Might not have the quality you require.

2) use mono 1 channel:

```
mRecorder.setAudioChannels (1)

// Sets the number of audio channels for recording. Call this method before 
// prepare().
// Usually it is either 1 (mono) or 2 (stereo).
```

Comment: the quality is loss , and is not like i want it  :(

Comment: can you add item (3) which shows how to use a bit depth of 8 instead of a typical default of 16 bits per sample

Comment: AudioFormat class allows you to set  ENCODING_PCM_8BIT and ENCODING_PCM_16BIT. This can then be used by AudioTrack and AudioRecord. Possibly this is not available for MediaRecorder. Also, 8 bits per sample may not work well on some devices.